# Programmatically interacting with a console application

Tags: c#, console

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Menu");
            Console.WriteLine("====");
            Console.WriteLine("1. print \"Hello\"");
            Console.WriteLine("2. print \"world!\"");
            Console.WriteLine("3. write something to echo");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Quit");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            char c = str.ToCharArray()[0];

            if (c == '1')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            }
            else if (c == '2')
            {
                Console.WriteLine(", world!");
            }
            else if (c == '3')
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", input);
            }
            else if (c == '4')
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose, the above program compiles into `main~1.exe`.

Now, I have written another C# console application that will programmatically execute `main~1.exe` and let the user send inputs and return the output from the `main~1.exe`.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Start the main~1.exe process
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "main~1.exe";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.Start();

        // Read and print the initial menu
        string menu = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(menu);

        // Loop to allow the user to send inputs and receive output
        while (true)
        {
            // Read the user's input
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            // Write the input to the process's standard input stream
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(input);

            // Read the process's output and print it to the console
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
}
```

However, it is not working as expected.

the output screen doesn't show anything.

It doesn't show any sign that it is interacting with the `main~1.exe`.

**What am I doing wrong in the second source code?**

Comment: You are running ``main~1.exe`` from debug path or release?

Comment: @sa-es-ir, debug path.

Comment: that's the problem I think, can you test it with release?

Comment: @sa-es-ir, the release doesn't even produce the initial menu.

Comment: You mean, no error no output?

Comment: @sa-es-ir, Yes. No error, no output.

Comment: The point is the first process didn't finish so this line ``process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`` is waiting until the process exited. You can workaround with events or read line by line.

Comment: @sa-es-ir, Can you show me a little bit?

Comment: You are using `ReadKey` not `ReadLine`. ReadKey expects a key press, not input from a redirected console input (that's what I guess from your error message - but that's what I suspected before I saw the error message)

Comment: @Flydog57, Changed the source code already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `main~1.exe` is a long-running process and `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` will block you app because it's waiting for process exit.

You need to use event on output received like this:

```cs
....
process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            }
        });

        process.Start();

        // Asynchronously read the standard output of the spawned process.
        // This raises OutputDataReceived events for each line of output.
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        

        // Loop to allow the user to send inputs and receive output
        while (true)
        {
            // Read the user's input
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            // Write the input to the process's standard input stream
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(input);
        }
```

Comment: @Anmolkansal If it was helpful for you please vote up so that others can use ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are using ReadToEnd() to read output from the child process.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=net-7.0

Relevant section:

> ReadToEnd assumes that the stream knows when it has reached an end. For interactive protocols in which the server sends data only when you ask for it and does not close the connection, ReadToEnd might block indefinitely because it does not reach an end, and should be avoided.

So basically, the stream never ends for the lifetime of the application so it can't be read to end, thus blocking indefinitely.